# write values from multidimensional array to .csv-file

Tags: c, csv, multidimensional-array

I am writing C-program that in the end will contain two large 2-dimensional arrays that I need to export to two csv.files.

The arrays (doubles) are 10000 rows long, and between 8 and 30 columns long, depending on what the user define, example below:

```
int NOS = 10000;
int Tau_length = 15;
Energy_system_Array[NOS][Tau_length];
```

I have created two file pointers:

```
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
```

At the end of the program, I have written these lines:

```
int array_rowit, array_colit;
fp1 = fopen("Energyarray.csv", "w");//create a file
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        return 0;
    }
for (array_colit = 0; array_colit<Tau_length; array_colit++){
    for (array_rowit = 0; array_rowit< start_measure; array_rowit++){
        fprintf(fp1, Energy_system_array[array_rowit,array_colit]);
        fclose(fp1);
    }
}
```

But when I compile the c-code, this is the message I get:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:413:22: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'fprintf'
         fprintf(fp1, Energy_system_array[array_rowit,array_colit]);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:1:0:
C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:378:15: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'double'
   int __cdecl fprintf(FILE * __restrict__ _File,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...);
               ^~~~~~~
```

I am a real novice when it comes to C-programing, so I hope someone can help me with this.I have searched around for different guides, but I haven't found any that describes my situation exactly.

I should mention that the csv files should be overwritten for each run of the program. It cannot save the values from an earlier run of the program.

Comment: Roughly: `fprintf(fp1, Energy_system_array[array_rowit,array_colit]);`-> `fprintf(fp1, "%lf,", Energy_system_array[array_rowit,array_colit]);`. But you need one `fprintf(fp1, "\n"); ` more to print the end of line, I let you find out where as an exercise.

Comment: @Johan OK, no need to be sorry for being a novice. The message says essentially "error: incompatible type for argument 2, ... " that means that the type of the second argument you provided to `fprintf` is not correct. `fprintf` expects a `const char*`, but you provided a `double`.

Comment: So may be OP needs first to decode the error message and may be read the manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the whole array as CSV, use:

```
for (array_colit = 0; array_colit<Tau_length; array_colit++){
    for (array_rowit = 0; array_rowit< start_measure; array_rowit++){
        fprintf(fp1, "%lf%s",Energy_system_array[array_rowit,array_colit],
                (array_rowit<start_measure-1?",":""));
    }
    fprintf(fp1,"\n");
}
fclose(fp1);
```

Notes:

- append a comma after each value but the last one
- add a newline after every row
- close the file *only* once everything has been written out.